# Get json object from API, modify & post it using C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio, async-await

Below is my code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    SetBase();
    //Console.ReadLine();
}

public static async void SetBase()
{
    var baseAddress = new Uri("https://google.com/");
    var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress };
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json");
    var content = new StringContent("{ \"postUserLogin\":{ \"login\":\"username\", \"password\":\"password\", \"remember\":1,\"verify_level\":0 }}", System.Text.Encoding.Default, "application/json");
    try
    {
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/account/login", content);

        using (var newresponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(viewURL + viewurlParameters))
        {
            if (newresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {                
                string responseData = await newresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JObject json = JObject.Parse(responseData);

                //Get input from User
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                //Make changes to json object according to input                
                //And Post Json object
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

All code after: `var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/account/login", content);` won't get executed.

But, if I uncomment the line `Console.Readline()` in `Main` the remaining steps get executed. Please help.

Comment: We can not guess the issue or solution without seeing the you have written. You need to share the relevant code and explain what exact issue you are facing along with expected behavior and the actual behavior of the code.

Comment: I will add the code in sometime. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, don't put them in a loop. Please add the code that is not working in future to avoid your question being deleted.

Do them in order:

1. Call API with Login Credentials to get a token string
2. Hit API with your request for data and your Token
3. Logout of API if that is asked for as the next steps may take ages
4. Do User Interaction
5. Add new items to total list
6. If there are new items Do step 1 again
7. Hit API endpoint with the data upload and your new token.